# goroutine different behaviour for statement execution and function execution

Tags: go, go-http

Can anyone explain the difference between the following two calls regarding the goroutines?

## Method 1

```
fmt.Println("Starting srv")
go LOGGER.Error(srv.ListenAndServe())
fmt.Println("Starting intSrv")
go LOGGER.Error(intSrv.ListenAndServe())
```

This stopes after executing the "Starting srv"

## Method 2

```
go func() {
    fmt.Println("Starting srv")
    srv.ListenAndServe()
}()

go func() {
    fmt.Println("Starting intSrv")
    intSrv.ListenAndServe()
}()
```

This executes both "Starting srv" and "Starting intSrv"

Why the behaviour is different?

Comment: Can you include a running minimal example? The first program should not behave as you described.

Comment: @bserdar Changed the program a bit, Actually forgot to include the LOGGER as i thought it doesn't have any significance but that LOGGER is causing the problem not sure why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
go LOGGER.Error(srv.ListenAndServe())
```

The above statement evaluates the arguments to `LOGGER.Error()` first, then creates a goroutine and runs `LOGGER.Error()`. However, `srv.ListenAndServe` never returns.

Answer (score 2):

Goroutine function parameters are evaluated in the calling goroutine.

In the following statement:

```
go LOGGER.Error(srv.ListenAndServe())
```

the expression `srv.ListenAndServe()` is evaluated before starting the goroutine to log the error.  The call to `srv.ListenAndServe()` does not return until the server exits (because the server was stopped or the listener encountered an error).

Use this code to start the server and log the error returned from the server.

```
go func() { LOGGER.Error(srv.ListenAndServe()) }()
```